# Working of SQL JOINS in this example

Tags: mysql, join

Ok so i was learning sql joins and was curious to try all joins on the following table:

Table name Demo1:
A
1
1
1
1
1

Table name Demo2: 
B
1
1
1
1
1 
[image]

To my amazement no matter which join i apply i end up with same 25 entries. I am sure about cross join since it gives all combination but what about the other joins how are they returning the same answers for these two tables.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @ Daniel Tran My question is whats the reason that all joins are producing the same result i.e 25 entries ? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Its producing always same result due to same values in your both tables.

Comment: @RaviRoshan is it because the on condition?

Comment: No .. update values of any one table and insert some different values like 2,3,4 etc instead of only 1

Comment: ty..did that and it doesnt show the entries that differ as per the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How join statement work is it pick up all entries from the first table
the for every entry, it pick all entries from the second table that is sastified by the on condition.

Hence, the number of result in this case = number of records in A * number of records in B = 25.

Comment: So i can say if you have same values in two tables every join will work as a cross join?